# c# - Any way to get list of files in a logical drive ( path error )?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an app for myself that backup the files which I've chosen before! I select which logical drives to add to a list and it should get list of files in the path and do the other stuff I told it :)

I can possibly say that i searched all the web! I tried to combine path, get driveinfo and ..... last code I, trying is this :

```
foreach (var drivename in driveslist)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(drivename, "*.*");
}
```

Edit: `driveslist` contains:

```
C
E
D
```

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ E'.'

Comment: How do you select drives? Debug and show what's inside `driveslist`.

Comment: im using a telegram bot and in there i select the drive(s) i want to backup ! list of drives is looking like this :  
C
D
E

Comment: You have to use full path, not just the drive name. For example:  Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\");

Comment: files will add , remove and etc in time

Comment: Can you show us what's inside `driveslist` ?

Comment: C
E
D
(other drives if it is available )

Comment: `C:\ E`? Do you have a folder in the root of C: called ` E` (that's a SPACE followed by a E)? If not (which seems likely) then there's your problem.

Comment: Just `C E D`? are they three separate strings? Do they have the colon and backslash that identifies them as drive letters and not directory names?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. Also be clear which version of .NET Framework / Core you are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems GetFiles doesn't understand that it is a drive you want to list.

Try ensuring you driveslist contains something like {@"C:\", @"D:\"} etc.

Edit:
Or if you're not in control of the upstream list just do:

```
foreach (var drivename in driveslist)
{
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles($"{drivename}:\\", "*.*");
}
```

Edit2:
I'm very surprised this doesn't work. the following code works on my machine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var driveslist = new[] {"C"};

        foreach (var drivename in driveslist)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles($"{drivename}:\\", "*.*");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get files of a logical drive and it starts from path C:\ idk what to do !

Comment: how to combine the path ? I think that maybe this is the problem !

I have the drive letter (e.g. => "C")

Comment: I tried ! 
The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: Could you post the updated System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException text?

Comment: it is giving me this error now :
 System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

Comment: Try my full example

Comment: Again says " The given path's format is not supported. "

Comment: Ok, try this then. Skip the asterisks and just do Directory.GetFiles($"{drivename}:\\");

Comment: 'The given path's format is not supported.'
Still this thing

Comment: I can't let this go... can you try:  Directory.GetFiles($"{drivename.Trim()}:\\"); ?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if `driveslist` contains the string `'C:\ E'`, which isn't a valid path.

I just tried:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.*");
```

and it works. I think you're blaming `GetFiles` but the problem is actually in the path.

If you just ask for `e` (without the colon and slash) it will think you want a subfolder called `e` of the current directory.

Comment: The error is like this because it can't find the path of E:\\ and it goes like C:\\E

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If it can't find e, it would say `Could not find a part of the path 'e:\\'` Please show us the content of `driveslist`

Comment: I thought so - see the last line of my answer: If you just ask for `e` (without the colon and slash) it will think you want a subfolder called e of the current directory.